# Slider.js on Rails 3.1

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, slider

Is it possible to use [Slider.js](http://greweb.fr/slider/) with Rails 3.1 ? 
Is there any integration example ?

UPDATE:

I can get Slider.js in my Rails 3.1 asset pipeline but how can I call it from HTML(haml) ?

I'd like to incorporate chart generated by controller#action page via google_visualr gem (which inject an IFRAME of google chart) ..., follow a chart sample which I'd like to put inside Slider.js carousel: http://gitwatcher.com/

the object I'd like to slide is actually

```
<div id="chart" style="position: relative;">
    <iframe height="540" frameborder="0" width="860" scrolling="no" name="Drawing_Frame_82178"
     id="Drawing_Frame_82178" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use any Javascript library with Rails 3.1.  Rails 3 is javascript agnostic.  Even better is the fact that Rails 3 comes with jQuery, so Slider.js will not have to worry about any framework conflicts.

If you want specifics on how to use it, you need to give an idea of what you want to do with it.

Comment: I need a carousell like in Demo of http://greweb.fr/slider/ which will call a controller#action page instead of jpg image.

Comment: How, exactly, does this relate to Rails though?  Are you going to use a Rails model to populate the images?  If not, this should just be standard Javascript/HTML.

Comment: yes ..., I have a controller/model which generate an IFRAME with few charts (google charts via google_visualr gem) and I'd like to "incapsulate" those charts into a slider/carousel

Comment: this is the chart I'd like to get into slider/carousel http://gitwatcher.com/ ... see UPDATE

Comment: It appears that the current version of this library will only slide images.  Perhaps you should look for another that will slide html or SVG.

Comment: oh nooo ..., any suggestion ?

Comment: Question: why do you run the chart in an iframe?

Comment: that's actually the way google_visualr gem works: https://github.com/winston/google_visualr,  but there are securely many others ways

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm going to have to punt at this point.  I am neither familiar with that gem or the visualization APIs from Google.  However, the answer your original question, you should be able to use any Javascript library with Rails.